# Cannot solve LNK 2001 error in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, lnk2001, lnk2005

I am working on a very big project, some hundred of .c and .h files, so I just cannot upload them here. I am running the **Release** in **Visual** **Studio**.

I am getting these errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project Path    File    Line    Source  Suppression State   Tool
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _drawExitSurface raytrace    C:\Users\Winter\Desktop\Newfolder   C:\Users\Winter\Desktop\Newfolder\ray-main.obj  1   Build       Link

Severity    Code    Description Project Path    File    Line    Source  Suppression State   Tool
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _calcDampingandImpulseResponse   raytrace    C:\Users\Winter\Desktop\Newfolder   C:\Users\Winter\Desktop\Newfolder\ray-main.obj  1   Build       Link
```

And others, as shown in the picture below:
[image]

I found that that the ray-main.obj, Raytrace-SINGLE.obj and Raytrace-STRAYL.obj are in Release folder, so I did this: search them down in the solution explorer, right click and click Include in Project. Also, in the Property->Linker-> Input-> Additional Dependencies, I included the paths to the mentioned obj files.

Can anyone please help?
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The error **unresolved external symbol _drawExitSurface** means that you forgot to link the obj or lib file which contain the symbol `_drawExitSurface`. Or you forgot to compile the source that include the symbol.

Comment: @khabbabzakaria Did you see my answer? Did you found the source code or library file corresponding to _drawExitSurface  (Search without underscore which is probably added by the compiler).